# IllegalArgumentException: /tmp/zookeeper/myid file is missing

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to configure Kafka on multiple instances of EC2 by following [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mkanchwala/fbfdd5ef866a58a77f6e) , but I am getting following error:

I am running this command:

```
$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties &
```

[1](https://gist.github.com/mkanchwala/fbfdd5ef866a58a77f6e) 13308

**Error**:

```
[2017-03-22 08:21:00,314] ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing config/zookeeper.properties
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:123)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:101)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /tmp/zookeeper/myid file is missing
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:350)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:119)
    ... 2 more
```

My `zookeeper.conf` is as shown below:

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
#clientPort=2181
clientPort=2080
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0


server.1=ec2-<GLOBAL_IP_1>.amazonaws.com:2888:3888
server.2=ec2-<GLOBAL_IP_2>.amazonaws.com:2888:3888
#add here more servers if you want
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
tickTime=2000
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> When the server starts up, it knows which server it is by looking for
>   the file `myid` in the data directory.

Create a file named `myid` under the `dataDir` i.e., `/tmp/zookeeper` for every Zookeeper server.

The `myid` file should contain the corresponding server number, in ASCII (For ex: `1`),  as the only entry in it.

Comment: What should be the entry in my case ??

Comment: For host `ec2-<GLOBAL_IP_1>.amazonaws.com`, it is `1` and for `ec2-<GLOBAL_IP_2>.amazonaws.com` it is `2`.